# How to only stop at a breakpoint after some line was executed?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

Frequently, I want to pause at a specific line while debugging, but only after another line was executed. Often, this JavaScript code was machine-generated (for example, by JSP or PHP), or should be built (e.g. by Grunt), which can be a bit annoying to do every time I want to add a breakpoint. How to stop at a specific line in this case?

For example, I have two functions, `f_a()` and `f_b()` that are called this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  f_a();
}

f_b();
f_a();
```

(*[Running example](http://tilde.club/~brandizzi/test.html)*)

I want to add a breakpoint inside `f_a()`, but only stop at this function after `f_b()` is called. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do the following:

1. Add a breakpoint to `f_b()`.
2. Make this breakpoint conditional. As the condition, set a variable (let us say, `pause_at_f_a`) to `true`. We do not want to pause inside `f_b()`, so we use the coma operator to return `false`. The condition is then

   ```
   pause_at_f_a = true, false
   ```

   [image: Adding conditional breakpoint to like that should enable other breakpoint.]
3. Add a breakpoint to `f_a()`. The condition of this breakpoint should be the `paused_at_f_a` variable.

   [image: Check for set variable on the breakpoint that should pause.]

A possible annoyance is that the breakpoint will stay enabled after we check whatever we want to check. That's why I use yet another step:

4. Instead of merely checking if the variable is `true`, unset it as well if it is true, use this condition:

   ```
   pause_at_f_a ? (pause_at_f_a = false, true) : false
   ```

The conditional can be anything. One can use counters as well. The core of the trick is to use a breakpoint to set variables. Here is the result:

[image: A debugging session with the trick.]

Comment: So you answered your own question within 1 minute? Seems reasonable.

Comment: @RJM Oh, i see. Did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write `debugger;` in your code, and the browser dev tools will stop on that code line.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Yeah, I use it a lot, too, but I could only get it working by editing the source code and reloading the page. It is the best way when the script is easy to change, but it can be complicated if the script is autogenerated, or demands a lot of building. It is a common case on my routine, unfortunately...

Comment: BTW here is a good question: is it possible to edit the code "on the fly" to add the `debugger` command?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would guess so. But then it would probably be better to just set breakpoints in the dev console.